# Package not removed: python-swiftclient 3.5.0

Tags: apt, package-management

I installed this package "python-swiftclient 3.5.0" using `sudo apt install python3-swiftclient` but when I try to remove it using `sudo apt-get remove python-swiftclient`. I get the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Package 'python-swiftclient' is not installed, so not removed

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

But when I type `swift --version` . I get this message:

```
python-swiftclient 3.5.0
```

Please help me as I am new to ubuntu. I am running Lubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong package name:

The name of the package you installed is `python3-swiftclient`.

You tried to remove the package with `sudo apt-get remove python-swiftclient` but you should have used `sudo apt-get remove python3-swiftclient`